# Problems changing TextView's text inside a listener

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to make a `TextView` look like a timer and control the time displayed with a `SeekBar`.

First, I get the message the `TextView` must be a Final but when I change that I can't change the `TextView` with setText in the listener.

How can I fix this code?

```
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    final TextView timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeView);

    seekBar.setMax(600);
    seekBar.setProgress(30);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            int minutes = progress / 60;
            int seconds = progress - (progress * 60);

            timeView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes), ":", Integer.toString(seconds));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indeed the simple solutions is to simply change the line of code where the OP wishes to use `setText()` inside the `onProgressChanged()` method: There is no override for the `setText()` method that handles those parameters. Simple solution(as stated in many answers):

```
timeView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds));
```

---

**But...digging deeper**
**TL;DR**

Originally, the OP wanted to simply use `TextView timeView` in the `onCreate()` method, but was warned by the compiler that they needed to add `final` in front of `TextView timeView` in order to be able to use `timeView` inside the anonymous inner class `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()`.

However, in general, the key word `final` indicates that the variable cannot be altered after initialization. Although a bit confusing **in this special case**  using `final` will allow changes to the `TextView` using `setText()`.

The primary problem is scope. `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()` is an anonymous inner class and `onCreate()` is the enclosing block. This (basically) means that the inner class does not actually belong to `onCreate()` and that `timeView` is outside the **scope** of the method `onProgressChanged()`.

Certainly, adding `final` to the method variable `TextView timeView` will "fix" the problem--**in this special case (and some like it), but not all cases**; therefore, I believe that using `final` is counter-intuitive.

Consider a variable `int count = 0` or `String showTime = "Show time";` interior to `onCreate()` but outside the anonymous inner class. The compiler will again throw a warning that the variables must be declared `final` if they are to be used within the anonymous inner class. But by doing so, they can no longer be altered. In fact, the code will not even compile if one were to attempt to change the values. By making `TextView timeView;` a class variable (ie. moving it outside the `onCreate()` method) the scope of this field will increase to include the anonymous inner class. The same is true for the variable `int count = 0` or `String showTime = "Show time";`--making them class variable would also increase their scope to include the anonymous inner class so that they can be used and altered inside the method `onProgressChanged()`. Therefore, it is my opinion that using class variables instead of `final` is more intuitive.

Check the Java Docs:
[Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing)
[Accessing Members of an Enclosing Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)

Comment: The code works fine with `final TextView timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeView);` inside `onCreate()`. Try it. The only problem is `setText()`

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation!

Comment: @Ginixx what explanation? Your code worked with the declaration inside onCreate().

Comment: @forpas :: That is correct. If you edit your answer and add an explanation as to why `final` will achieve the same result and why despite having `timeView` declared `final` that does not prevent the `timeView` from changing the displayed value, then I will gladly ask Ginixx to award the points to you.

Comment: The OP already has `final` in his code, he did not have to change anything else than setText(). All the other "explanations" in your answer are completely **wrong**.

Comment: Also you don't need to ask the OP anything. You should delete your answer because it is **misleading** and **wrong**.

Comment: @forpas :: No they are not completely wrong. If you do not understand, then I do not intend to clarify it for you. Perhaps you should try your solution on an Android device that does not support Java 8. And perhaps you should also realize that your solution also fails if the OP attempted to add a variable (`String` for example) to the `onCreate()` method and access it from within the `onProgressChanged()` method...go ahead declare it `final`.... enjoy!

Comment: You're still trying to change the subject to something that does not exist. **The OP has final in his code** so there is no problem or needed explanation for that. You provide info that is **wrong**.

Comment: *The primary problem is you have declared the TextView to be local within the onCreate() method* your words not mine and all of it is **wrong**.

Comment: I don't *feel* your answer is wrong, **you just said that it is wrong**. The problem has nothing to do with scope. It's a simple syntactical problem and you maximized it and the result is that you mislead the OP and everybody who will read it.

Comment: @forpas :: I have no problem with the down vote. You have expressed your objections. Good day to you Sir.

Comment: @Barns: IMHO the question was not well-written, and the response by the asker was similarly unclear. I think the `setText()` change was all that was needed (though personally I'd probably use a field, as your first code snippet used, since I'll probably need that `TextView` elsewhere). At this point, though, your answer is a bit convoluted. You can't delete it yourself, as it is the accepted answer. You could flag it for moderator attention and ask for them to delete the answer, or you could make some fixes (e.g., add a TL;DR to the top).

Comment: @CommonsWare :: Thanks for the response -- and again my apology for the hi-jack. My question to you: is my answer in regard to the issue of scope wrong and misleading as forpas has suggested?

Comment: @Barns: There are two parts to the original problem. One (scope) the OP solved via `final`, seemingly just by following the compiler advice. The other (`setText()`) presumably is where the OP was stuck. Having an answer that covers the reason why `final` was part of the overall solution and offers alternatives is fine... as secondary material. IMHO, the primary material should be about the still-outstanding problem (`setText()`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `public Textview`.
So replace this line

```
final TextView timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeView);
```

With

```
timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeView);
```

and add this

```
TextView timeView;
```

Over your `OnCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is the syntax of `setText()` method.  
`setText()` takes one `String` (CharSequence) as an argument, so change this:

```
timeView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes), ":", Integer.toString(seconds));
```

to this:

```
timeView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds));
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
timeView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes), ":", Integer.toString(seconds));
```

to

```
timeView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes)+ ":"+ Integer.toString(seconds));
```

Comment: I have a question for you: apart from copy/paste will you give any explanation for the solution you propose?

Comment: you have to concat minutes,: and seconds,which is possible by + operator,because setText accept only one string.

Comment: Right, and what's wrong with the OP's way? Is he doing something wrong?

Comment: String concatenation not possible using , we must use + operator.

Comment: So when you copied my answer why did you leave all this info out and pasted just the code?

Comment: sorry i'm not copied your code , actually i was late some minute from you.

Comment: You were late 13 mins! Did you type for 13 mins this answer? And when you saw there exists already this answer what did you do?

Comment: you can see i'm new here,thats why i take time.really i'm not copied your code,but if you hurt and think that i copied your code,then i'm sorry. plz finish it now.

Comment: Since you are new here take your time and read the questions and post valuable answers **when needed**.